# Select_tag with elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5

I try to pass 2 options for search. First [:q] for input text by visitor and another one from model camping "nomdep" (like departement in english). When i try to search by input it's works, but since i try to add select_tag i have an error

**ERROR**
*undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass*

I m lost, do u have any ideas ?

Sorry for my english, i m french.

Home_controler.rb

```
 def index
      if params[:q].nil?
        "Entrez un mot clef"
      else
        @campings = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search params[:q,:nomdep]
        @camping = Camping.all
    end
    end

def result
      if params[:q].nil?
        @campings = []
      else
        @campings = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search(params[:q]).page(params[:page]).per(14).results
      end
end
```

View

```
<div class="search">
        <%= form_tag(result_path, method: :get) %>
        <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], class:"search-query form-control" %>
                    <%= select_tag(:nomdep, options_for_select(@camping)) %>

              <%= submit_tag "Partez", class:"btn btn-danger", name: nil %>
    </div>
```

---

**EDIT**
Now i dont have any error but the search dont work if [:q] empty. So if i only select_tag => no result.

How fix this ?

My full home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @camping = Camping.all
      if params[:q].nil?
        "Entrez un mot clef"
      else
        @campings = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search params[:q, :nomdep]
    end
    end

  def result
      if params[:q].nil?
        @campings = []
      else
        @campings = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search(params[:q]).page(params[:page]).per(14).results
      end

end
end
```

my view

```
<div class="search">
            <%= form_tag(result_path, method: :get) %>
                        <%= select_tag :nomdep, options_from_collection_for_select(@camping, :id, :nomdep), prompt: "Département" %>
                  <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], class:"search-query form-control" %>
                  <%= submit_tag "Partez", class:"btn btn-danger", name: nil %>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@camping = Camping.all
```

This variable will be nil unless :q was passed in params to index action. options_for_select(@camping) will attempt to call #map on this variable and raise error when it is not initialized.

You should make sure it is initialized. For example, try rewriting your action:

```
 def index
      @camping = Camping.all
      if params[:q].nil?
        "Entrez un mot clef"
      else
        @campings = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search params[:q]
      end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks @Baradzed but no works totally. I can display page home but 2 things. 1) Names of departement dont show i have only this <Camping%3A0x9f9c888>... 2) when i submit search with [:q] empty and select association i have no result. So what can i do to fix this ?

Comment: I edit my topic to add def result, how can i do for the search work ?

Comment: To address point (1): Rails does not know which properties of Camping object constitute value and text for select options. You can use another helper and specify these properties, example: `options_from_collection_for_select(@camping, :id, :nomdep)`

Comment: Great, that fix problem 1. Search dont work with empty params [:q] how can fix this ? url look like this http://localhost:3000/result?utf8=%E2%9C%93&nomdep=6&q=

Comment: The last two parameters to the helper above are specifying value and text for options. You should choose them to suit your models. My guess is that for this searchbox, `@camping, :nomdep, :nomdep` might be what you need.

Comment: Looks to me that your app expects that `nomdep` will be passed in search params, that's why I suggested that `@camping, :nomdep, :nomdep` might work better for your app.

Comment: Ok now i dont have id in url but string of nomdep. But search dont work... i dont know why, it illogical. I have empty :q but no-empty :nomdep so normaly result could display something no ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122053/discussion-between-baradzed-and-nicolaswecandoit).

Answer (score 0):

I want to say a big big big THANKS to @Baradzed ! We talked yesterday and he find a solution thats work perfectly !

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @camping = Departement.all
      if params[:q].blank? || params[:nomdep].blank?
      @campings = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search params[:nomdep]
      else
      @campings = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search params[:q]

    end
  end



  def result

    querystring = params.slice(:nomdep, :other_param, :any_params_except_q_because_we_will_process_q_separately)
    .select{|k,v| v.present?}
    .map {|key, value| "#{key}:\"#{value.gsub(/([#{Regexp.escape('\\+-&|!(){}[]^~*?:/')}])/, '\\\\\1') }\""}
    .join(" AND ")

    freetext = params[:q]
    freetext.gsub!(/([#{Regexp.escape('\\+-&|!(){}[]^~*?:/')}])/, '\\\\\1')

    querystring = ["*#{freetext}*",querystring].select{|v| v.present?}.join(" AND ") if params[:q].present?

    if querystring.blank?
    flash[:notice] = "Aucune mots clefs"
    redirect_to action: :index and return
    else
    @campings = Camping.__elasticsearch__.search(
    query: { query_string: {
    query: querystring
    }}).page(params[:page]).per(14).results
    end


        @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@campings) do |camping, marker|
          marker.lat camping.latitude
          marker.lng camping.longitude
          marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/campings/infowindow", :locals => { :camping => camping})
          marker.picture ({
            "url" => "http://avantjetaisriche.com/map-pin.png",
            "width" =>  29,
            "height" => 32})
        end
end
end
```

view

```
 <div class="search">
            <%= form_tag(result_path, method: :get) %>
                        <%= select_tag :nomdep, options_from_collection_for_select(@camping, :nomdep, :nomdep), prompt: "Département" %>
                  <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], class:"search-query form-control" %>
                  <%= submit_tag "Partez", class:"btn btn-danger", name: nil %>
```